# How to build an ExpectationBase object?

Tags: qiskit, programming, vqe

I'm trying to wrap my head around the expectation argument in Qiskit's `VQE` class, so to understand it I'm trying to create an ExpectationBase object to understand it better, but I'm getting nowhere. Can anyone give a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VQE computes the expectation values of the input operator with respect to the parameterized ansatz circuit. There are different ways to compute this expectation value, e.g. you could

- convert operator to a matrix, the ansatz circuit to a statevector and compute the dot-product, or
- convert the operator to Pauli strings, diagonalize the ansatz circuit in each basis of the Pauli strings and measure.

The `expectation` argument allows you to choose the kind of expectation computation you want to use.

- `qiskit.aqua.operators.MatrixExpectation` does the dot product
- `qiskit.aqua.operators.PauliExpectation` does the Pauli string transform (this is what you would do on real quantum hardware)
- `qiskit.aqua.operators.AerPauliExpectation` uses a special expectation value from Qiskit's Aer element

---

A bit more advanced:

If you were to create your own kind of expectation computation you can check how [`MatrixExpectation`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/master/qiskit/aqua/operators/expectations/matrix_expectation.py) or [`PauliExpectation`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/master/qiskit/aqua/operators/expectations/pauli_expectation.py) are implemented. They require some knowledge of how the operator flow in Aqua works though. In brief, the `ExpectationValue` provides a `convert` method that maps an operator expression that realizes the expectation value (something like `OperatorMeasurement @ StateFn`) to a new expression that implements your expectation value scheme. For `MatrixExpectation` this means converting all operators to matrices and for `PauliExpectation` this means converting the operator to Pauli strings and applying the right basis transformations to the ansatz circuit.

Comment: That's exactly what I want with the PauliExpectation: I want to have a custom circuit to act after the ansatz and then calculate the expectation, but the inner workings of the operator flow in aqua mess me up. Can you do a trivial example that I can follow after?

Comment: Why not just add the circuit to the input ansatz?

Comment: Because then all the pauliexpectation circuits would apply to that ansatz, and I want to add that new circuit to the final rotation layer to make measurements

Comment: Ah, so if you want to do it for PauliExpectation then the hacky way would be to add your circuit as last element of `ComposedOp` here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/b29596800447c3130a20ec72a18b7fd8ed9fdb2f/qiskit/aqua/operators/converters/pauli_basis_change.py#L228. The correct way would be to pass your own `replacement_fn` by changing that L80 in the PauliExpectation (you could add that as option in the initializer or so).